# Image in base64 not displaying in Safari

Tags: javascript, safari

I have a PHP code that sends a base64 string like this:

```
data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4XxuRXhpZgAASUkqAAgAAAAMAAABBAABAAAAAAgAAAEBBAABAAAAAAYAAA8BAgAIAAAAngAAABABAgAJAAAApgAAABIBAwABA............
```

In my javascript code I have an editor where I place the image as bellow:

```
 var img = new Image();
    img.src = response.dataURL;
    editor.updateImage(img);
```

The image is loaded in FireFox, Chrome but in Safari it gives the following error: `TypeError: '[object BlobConstructor]' is not a constructor (evaluating 'new Blob([new Uint8Array(array)], {type: mimeString})')`

How can I fix this to work in all browsers please?

Thanks.

Comment: only is safari?

Comment: Please read the error message you've got before writing your quetion. Your problem is that `Blob` is not a constructor. This means that your version of Safari doesn't support `new Blob`, but still does know something about `Blob`. This means that you are using Safari 5.1 ~ 6 (5 years old). This means that you've got an open door to any malware on the web. This means that you should throw this right now and use a VirtualMachine, or even better a real osX to do your testings on Safari. Apple did stop their windows craziness in 2012 and never gave a single security patch from then.

Answer (score -1):

One possible solution would be to set your cross-origin after setting the `img.src`:

```
var img = new Image();
img.src = response.dataURL;
img.crossOrigin = 'Anonymous';
// Now set your image
editor.updateImage(img);
```

Another solution comes from the answer provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32357343/2803743):

> the problem seems to be that Safari will not render base64 images that does not have a number of character divisible by 4.
>   The solution to this problem is to pad your encoded string at the end using '=' characters. Here is a basic algorithm:

```
// b64str = 's/3eea4sp...' (or any base 64 encoded string)
while (b64str.length % 4 > 0) {
    b64str += '=';
}
```

Edit:

You could try switching from the deprecated `BlobBuilder` to `Blob`:

```
var imageBlob = new Blob([response.dataURL], {type: mimeString});    
var objurl = window.URL.createObjectURL(imageBlob));
var img = new Image();

img.src = objurl;
editor.updateImage(img);
```

Comment: whith adding pad (=) I get now in chrom InvalidCharacterError: String contains an invalid character

Comment: Added a workaround for Safari's deprecated `BlobBuilder`, maybe that works?

Comment: I found some links about the blob but I don't see how to use it in my editor instead of the image.

Comment: Any help please on the blob?

Comment: Edited my answer. I don't have access to Safari so can't really test the solution myself, sorry.