# Image not rendering in Safari Browser

Tags: html, image, browser, safari, cross-browser

I am displaying image in html by setting src property as base64 string. It is working perfectly for Chrome, Firefox, IE and Edge while Safari is not  rendering image.

```
<img alt="image" src="data:image/file.jpg;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAADIA..." />
```

Would appreciate your response.

Comment: Try [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27396376/base64-image-tag-in-safari-did-not-showed-up).

Comment: tried but no luck

Answer (score 0):

It appears that Safari is a bit fussy about rendering images with src provided in the form of base64 string.  There are reports that the length of base64 string is supposed to be divisible by 3 or by 4.  In that case you would pad the string with one, two, or three equal signs and check if your image is rendered in Safari.  In my case however, that did not work.  Then, I used different tool for converting my initial png image file to base64.  Surprisingly, that solved the problem.  The initial conversion, not rendered properly by Safari, was done on onlinepngtools.com, the second one (that worked) on base64-image.de.  To make it more interesting - all other small png images converted on onlinepngtools.com were displayed properly in Safari.  So, try padding your base64 src string with the equal sign, then use different conversion tool.